# Ошибка при запуске Visual Studio 2019 и 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Помоготе разобратся с ошибкой при запуске студии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Логи:*** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dp0dC2TRfmwpuaOhFQiMyCv5cdCGKZHK?usp=sharing

Comment: очень информативно

Comment: покажите файл, который указан в ошибке

Comment: когда запускаю студию видает ету ошибку, пробовал переустановить, не помогло, ошибка как в 19 так и в 17 студии

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dp0dC2TRfmwpuaOhFQiMyCv5cdCGKZHK?usp=sharing